# SQL: How to use grouping and condition at the same time in a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with such structure:

| id | product | company |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | table | A |
| 2 | table | B |
| 3 | table | C |
| 4 | chair | A |
| 5 | chair | B |
| 6 | sofa | A |
| 7 | sofa | C |

I need to find all products whose companies include both A and B. In the example above these would be `table` and `chair`.

I managed to write a query that will return products that have more than one companies:

```
SELECT product FROM table_name
GROUP BY product HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
order by COUNT(*) desc;
```

But I can’t make a selection taking into account certain companies, and not just their number.
I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT product
    FROM table_name
   WHERE company IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY product
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT company) = 2
ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc;
```

Comment: @ClearlyClueless I suggest you give it a try ;) *(It would require two levels of aggregation.)*

Comment: I stand corrected. In my head that should still work. In practice, it clearly does not. [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ca4876/6)

Comment: @ClearlyClueless This should help demonstrate why ; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ca4876/7

Comment: Its blatantly obvious when looking at it. Conceptually I knew it would be count = 1 each. I was thinking for some reason it would still roll  it up in the having line for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: There's no reason to use `COUNT(DISTINCT` here, and the `ORDER BY` makes no sense as the result will always be `2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, we can do it by self join on table on product column. Here is the example:

SELECT t1.product
from table_name t1, table_name t2
where t1.product=t2.product
and t1.company='A' and t2.company='B'